# Как исправить ошибку при выполнении программы?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пользователь (или несколько пользователей за одним компьютером) вводит слова. Начиная со второго введённого слова, программа проверяет, совпадает ли первая буква свежевведённого слова с последней буквой предыдущего. Если да, то программа работает дальше (считывает очередное слово). Если нет — выводит последнее на этот момент введённое слово и завершает работу.

```
a = input()
while True:
    b = input()
    if a[-1] != b[0]:
        print(b)
        break
        
    else:
        a = b
```

при тесте программы пишет такую ошибку:

```
wrong answer 1st lines differ - expected: 'тула', found: ''
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Эникейщик Я исправил код и прикрепил пример теста, но теперь выдает другую ошибку

Comment: А почему у вас `break` перед `print(a)`?

Comment: @gil9red да, спасибо, тоже заметил это сейчас

Comment: напишите тогда ответ и примите его, чтобы вопрос не лежал открытым